# Pointer to Integer Array versus Double Pointer to Integer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types

I would have thought that an integer array is of type pointer to integer, so that would mean that a pointer to an integer array is of type double pointer to integer. But the results that I am getting say otherwise. I have suspicion that the type integer array is not of type pointer to integer.

Here is my example:

```
int main(){
  int p[3]={1,2,3};
  int (*ptr)[3] = &p;
  int **ptr2 = &p;

  printf("%d\n",(*ptr)[0]);
  printf("%d\n",**ptr2);
  return 0;
}
```

**p** is of type 3 element integer array.

**&p** is of type pointer to 3 element integer array.

**ptr** is of type pointer to 3 element integer array.

**ptr2** is of type double pointer to integer

So my question is, if an integer array is a pointer to integer, why doesn't **ptr2** work as expected? Is the type double pointer to integer different from the type pointer to integer array? Any help clearing this up for me would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: An array is not a pointer. It will decay to a pointer to its first element when used as a value. Also, taking the address of an array gives a pointer to the first element of that array, not a pointer to some memory location with the address of the first element o the array. Make sure that your warnings are turned on, because `int **ptr2 = &p;` should cause some since you're assigning an `int *` to an `int **`.

Comment: `&p` is the same as `p` in this case

Comment: @alinsoar The value may be the same, but the **type** is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would have thought that an integer array is of type pointer to integer,

It is not. Arrays *decays* to pointers in many common circumstances, but they are not the same.

> so that would mean that a pointer to an integer array is of type double pointer to integer.

No it is not.

> why doesn't ptr2 work as expected?

`ptr2` is a pointer that contains the address of the array `p`. Dereferencing this with `*ptr2` would give the first element in `p`. Dereferencing this again would use the first element in `p` as an address, and give the value at that address.

This is why you should read the warnings from your compiler. Even without the flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra` (which you always should use) this code emits this warning:

```
k.c:6:16: warning: initialization of ‘int **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)[3]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   int **ptr2 = &p;
                ^
```

There you have it in plain text. `int **` is not compatible with `int(*)[3]`

Always read compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

While the innermost dimension of a multidimensional array in C readily converts to a pointer:

```
char (*p)[2][3][4]= //<pointer to an array of 2 or array of 3 of array of 4 char
    (char[5/*<- this one decays to a ptr*/][2][3][4]){0};
    //^array 5 of array 2 of arry 3 of array 4 of char
    ;
```

arrays and pointers are *very* different in C despite the confusingly identical syntax for indexing and dereferencing (which are both two sides of the same coin as: `x[index]` is the same as `*(x+index)` or `index[x]`).

I think this is a part of C where if you don't have context, the idea that the language maps directly to assembly breaks down most apparently.

Compare

```
char a[1][1][1][1]={{{{'a'}}}}; //1 byte
char ****b = &(char***){&(char**){&(char*){&(char){'b'}}}}; //1byte+4*ptr_sz
```

and now the code that [`****a` generates vs what `****b` generates](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SofEhd):

```
char get_a_char(void)
{
    return ****a;
}
char get_b_char(void)
{
    return ****b;
}
```

x86-64:

```
get_a_char:
        mov     al, BYTE PTR a[rip]
        ret
get_b_char:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR b[rip]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     al, BYTE PTR [rax]
        ret
```

When you dereference a multiply indirect pointer (`b`), you get a pointer chase.

When you dereference/subscript a multidimensional array, then your subscripts (zeros if you're just dereferencing) and the dimensions of the array are used to calculate an offset from a base, so you eventually either get an offsetted pointer (the same pointer if you're just derefing, just with a different type) if you deref/subscript through *just some* of the dimensions, or the same followed by a fetch from that address if you deref/subscript through all of them.

In your case `ptr` is `int (*)[3]` -- a pointer to an array of 3 int but `ptr2` is `int**` -- a pointer to a pointer to int.

When you do `ptr2[1][2]` you add 1 pointer size, fetch a pointer from there, and then add 2 int (target type) sizes to the fetched pointer
and fetch from there.

That's very different from when you do `ptr[1][2]` in which case you add one `int[3]` size to the base pointer and then 2 int sizes and fetch from there (a total of 1 fetch).

The types of `ptr` obviously cannot be compatible with the type of `ptr2`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, you can take the address of an array. the type of that is a generally not very useful "pointer to specific array type", not a generic pointer to pointer to content.

If you must, you can create a pointer that is equivalent to the array, and then take the address of that:

```
int p[] = {1,2,3};
int *q=p;
int **r=q;
```

But there is no way to shortcut this step, and you are dependent on the lifetime of that intermediate pointer.

Comment: So in the case of doing something like int * p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3); Then p would be of type pointer to int and in this case int **ptr = &p would work? Its strange because in that case p would act like an array but it wouldn't have that type.

Comment: Indeed, yopu can do that as well.

Comment: Why do you claim it's not useful to take the address of an array?  It might not be appropriate *for some particular purpose*, but that doesn't mean there is *no* purpose for it.

Comment: @John OK, it was a turn of phrase. In C the type of "pointer to array" isn't generally _very_ useful, compared to a pointer to the elements.

Comment: I suspect people who work with (*bona fide*) multi-dimensional arrays would disagree.  Pointers to arrays arise naturally and are very useful in that context.  I'd be prepared to accept that applying the address-of operator to an array is rarely what one really wants to do, but that's about array usage, not about the resulting pointer type.